# sinatra-flash gem isn't working

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I attempted to use the sinatra-flash gem with my application and get an "undefined local variable or method 'flash'" error when I try to run it.

my_app:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/flash'

class GGInfraUserManager < Sinatra::Base
enable :sessions
register Sinatra::Flash
```

...(rest of app)

```
post '/' do

flash[:error] = "Password must be a minimum of 8 characters" unless new_password.match /.{8}/
log.info "#{Time.now} password meets policy requirements"
end
redirect '/'
end
```

In my erb view file (at the top):

```
<div id="flash" class="notice">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
<%= flash.now[:error] %>
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me how to correct this error so that the flash functionality will work?

Comment: a guess: so only after doing POST '/' ```flash``` variable is set. If you do GET '/' before doing post ```flash``` variable is not set by that time.

Comment: Shouldn't the class be "error" instead of "notice?"

Comment: With Sinatra flash, you can use :error https://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-flash

Answer (score 3):

While the gem seems comfortable enough to use why not implement it yourself. It's in fact just a couple of lines:

```
#in your app.rb:
helpers do

  #a partial helper
  def partial(template, locals = {})
    slim template, :layout => false, :locals => locals
  end

  #the flash helper
  def flash
    @flash = session.delete(:flash)
  end
end

get '/' do
  session[:flash] = ["Some happy news", "alert-success"]
end
```

Then you can add a partial view which I called partial_flash.slim

```
-if flash
  -message, status = @flash
  .alert class=(status) = message
```

You call that partial usually from your layout file or any other view that needs a flash message:

```
==partial :partial_flash
```

So a route is called, the layout is loaded and checks `if flash`. If there is, it displays a flash message with a specified class. I use Twitter Bootstrap, so `alert-success` is a green message box.

You can see an example app here: https://github.com/burningTyger/farhang-app